# Weird measurment speeds: writing to disc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, performance, nsfilemanager

I've got a .zip file in my bundle. I'm reading it via:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
fileManager.delegate = self;

NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSArray *bundleZipFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"zip" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *filePath = [bundleZipFile firstObject];
NSData *file =  [fileManager contentsAtPath:filePath];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] && file) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
        double fileSizeInBytes = [attributes[NSFileSize] doubleValue];
        NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:copy1FilePath error:nil];
        double timePassed1Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:copy1FilePath toPath:copy2FilePath error:nil];
        double timePassed2Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:copy2FilePath toPath:copy3FilePath error:nil];
        double timePassed3Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [fileManager createFileAtPath:copy4FilePath contents:file attributes:nil];
        double timePassed4Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [fileManager createFileAtPath:copy5FilePath contents:file attributes:nil];
        double timePassed5Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [fileManager createFileAtPath:copy6FilePath contents:file attributes:nil];
        double timePassed6Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        [file writeToFile:copy7FilePath atomically:YES];
        double timePassed7Ms = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
             // here I calculate times like
             double bytesPerSecond = fileSizeInBytes / timePassed3Ms;
             double MBps = bytesPerSecond / 1000000.0;
        });
    });
}
```

I wanted to test the saving speed on the iOS. After seeing results I'm confused:

```
FileSize: 88375520.000000    

Method: copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:
Copying 1 took: 1460.937977 milliseconds
Copying 2 took: 1770.565987 milliseconds
Copying 3 took: 1747.061014 milliseconds
Total copying took: 4978.564978
Bytes per second: 17751.203489
MB/s: 0.017751

Method: createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:
Save 1 took: 3752.479970 milliseconds
Save 2 took: 2313.687027 milliseconds
Save 3 took: 3230.316997 milliseconds
Total saving took: 9296.483994
Bytes per second: 9506.338102
MB/s: 0.009506

Method: writeToFile:atomically:
Bytes per second: 32301.891362
MB/s: 0.032302
```

So it seems, that keeping the data in buffer and only saving it is slower than reading from file and saving to another file :/. What is more I've tried to run only 3 first actions (only copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:) and results are much better:

```
FileSize: 88375520.000000    
Method: copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:
Copying 1 took: 14.973998 milliseconds
Copying 2 took: 3.435016 milliseconds
Copying 3 took: 2.867997 milliseconds
Total copying took: 21.277010
Bytes per second: 4153568.483964
MB/s: 4.153568
```

I've even achieved here ~12 MB/s when CPU is moreover free.

Can anybody please tell me why copying is faster than saving only and why 3 actions are faster than 3 out of 7..?

Comment: There seems to be an error in the math. Example 1: total size = 88MB * 3 = 264MB total copied. Total time is 5sec. Copy speed: 264/5 = 52.8MB/sec. There are similar math errors in the rest. A reality check would indicate that "MB/s: 0.017751" is just wrong.

Comment: Why would `createFileAtPath` be faster can probably be explained by OS optimization. Perhaps memory is utilized better. Perhaps it is a disk controller mode the system uses.

Comment: @Zaph Fact, I forgot I've calculated miliseconds and thought these are seconds. My bad - thanks. But still why does running only 3 first actions is so much faster than running 7 actions one by one?

Comment: It might be a good idea to correct your question. See my other response.

Comment: @Zaph Your other question tells about `createFileAtPath:`. Please do notice, that method `copyItemAtPath:` is slower when we call `createFileAtPath:` after it than alone, and that's what wonders me.